# Can't change password of FreeIPA admin - "Current password's minimum life has not expired"

Tags: kerberos, freeipa

We have a FreeIPA-based system, admin's password has expired and needs to be changed but the standard password changing procedure over SSH fails:

```
sashka@cellar ~ ssh admin@ipa.xxxxxxxxxx.com
admin@ipa.xxxxxxxxxx.com's password: 
Password expired. Change your password now.
Last failed login: Mon Jun 30 15:38:21 MSK 2014 from 116.10.191.195 on ssh:notty
There were 6071 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Wed Apr 16 19:28:54 2014
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user admin.
Current Password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
Password change failed. Server message: Current password's minimum life has not expired

Password not changed.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
Connection to ipa.xxxxxxxxxx.com closed.
```

If we try to change the password using `passwd` it fails too with the same error message:

```
[admin@ipa ~]$ passwd
Changing password for user admin.
Current Password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
Password change failed. Server message: Current password's minimum life has not expired

Password not changed.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
[admin@ipa ~]$
```

What should we do to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have somehow created a password policy with a minimum password life longer than the maximum password life.

Remember that the maximum is specified in *days* while the minimum is specified in *hours*. If you mix these up, then it's easy to do this.

To confirm it, check the existing password policy:

```
ipa pwpolicy-find

ipa pwpolicy-show global_policy
```

Log in with a second admin account and change the password policy.

For instance, to set a minimum life of 7 days and a maximum life of 90 days:

From the command line:

```
ipa pwpolicy-mod global_policy --minlife 168 --maxlife 90
```

From the web UI:

[image: Change IPA password policy Web UI]

The minimum life can also be set to zero to disable it.

Comment: Do these settings apply back to accounts which were created prior to policy modification? My current global password policy is 900 days of max lifetime and 2400 hours of min lifetime. I think the admin account had a default max lifetime of 90 days initially. So if it was remembered on account creation and not synchronized later when we set a new max lifetime the old max got lower than the new min!

Comment: The policy should take effect immediately. I'm not sure what's going on with your admin account. And that's really a quite long minimum lifetime. 100 days without being able to change a password seems rather excessive...